# How can I find out if a PNG file is 24 bit color or 32 bit color on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, colors, png

I have PNG image files on Mac OS X. How can I find out if an image is 24 bit color or 32 bit color?

Comment: Questions were merged, that's why there are duplicate answers.

Answer (score 24):

Mac OS X also comes with a utility built into it called [sips](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) that could be used to query and manipulate different attributes of image files. As an example, you could use the following command to display all image properties associated with the image:

```
sips -g all image.png
```

Comment: The relevant `sips` properties are `samplesPerPixel` and `bitsPerSample`.

Comment: By the way, if you can use another answer by 1:1 copying it, the question's most probably a duplicate. In this case, please don't answer it, but `flag` it for moderator attention to have it closed as a dupe instead.

Comment: Ah, so do you just choose 'it needs moderator attention', choose other, and then write in duplicate?

Comment: @Ryan: "It doesn't belong here" -> "Exact Duplicate" -> Paste link.

Answer (score 14):

[pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) will give a succinct description (and any errors, should they exist):

```
$ pngcheck *.png
OK: sample24.png (128x128, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 89.7%).
OK: sample32.png (128x128, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 78.0%).

No errors were detected in 2 of the 2 files tested.
```

Mac binaries available on supplied link.

Comment: If you are on a Mac and have [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), you can install it with: `brew install pngcheck`

Comment: Good answer - the sips suggestion didn't work for me - Both png-8 and png-24 files are reported as 8 bit sRGB. Another working answer is also `file *.png` - no extra installs required. png-8 will show as "colormap" whereas png-24 shows as "color RGB".

Answer (score 8):

[ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) `identify` utility (command line) will show you all sorts of info about images in a range of formats.

```
identify -verbose <image file>
```

If your image is 24 bit you will see:

```
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
```

If your PNG image is 32 bit you will see:

```
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
  alpha: 8-bit
```

There will be a lot of other information displayed as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can query Spotlight's metadata index using `mdls`:

```
mdls -name kMDItemBitsPerSample filename.png
kMDItemBitsPerSample = 32
```

---

The results seem a bit odd though. `mdls -name kMDItemHasAlphaChannel` might be more relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what has been suggested, Mac OS X comes with a utility built into it called [sips](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) that could be used to query and manipulate different attributes of image files. As an example, you could use the following command to display all image properties associated with the image:

```
sips -g all image.png
```