# How can I tell if my png is a 24 bit png?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out if a PNG file is 24 bit color or 32 bit color on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/148661/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-png-file-is-24-bit-color-or-32-bit-color-on-mac-os-x)

I am running MacOS X 10.6. I try 'Get Info' from an image, but it does not show if it is 24 bit png?

How can I tell if a png is a 24bit png on Mac OSX?